# The indentation is breaking when when I pull code from gerrit in visual studio code for C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I am pulling a C++ project from Gerrit and opening it in visual studio code for editing. But the indentation is totally broken when I am opening a file in visual studio code. But when I open the same file in another text editor the indentation is okay. I have checked other questions related to this one, but they didn't resolve my issue.

Comment: What are tab sizes are configured on your IDE? Does your IDE has some plugin installed with a clang format? And what does it mean "indentation is breaking"?

Comment: Switch your editor to show tabs visually. Such broken indentation is generally the result of some brain-dead editor/tool replacing either tabs with spaces or vice versa and tab widths not being the same in the involved tools. If you use tabs for indentation, make sure never to mix them with spaces, and never to use an editor/tool that converts them to spaces. Likewise, if you use spaces for indentation, make sure never to mix them with tabs, and never to use an editor/tool that silently converts runs of eight spaces to a tab.